# what is difference between address binding and paging in operating systems?

Tags: operating-system

both are the concepts of Operating System. I searched on address binding,and found answer that **it is mapping of logical address to physical address in main memory**.On the other side when I searched about Paging,**it also indicates the same**.Became confused in both.Please help me in this question...
Thanking you in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Address binding can map a logical address to physical memory, or to a location on a disk. Paging is specific part of address binding. Pages are large blocks of memory, all the same size. To map a logical address to a physical one in main memory or in disk, first you find the page ( for example 4K block ) it is in, and then where it is inside that page.